# Node.js: new File from fetched PNG URL

Tags: node.js, file, blob, storage

I'm currently trying to upload an image to Supabase's Storage, this looks [fairly simple from the docs](https://supabase.io/docs/guides/storage#upload-a-file)

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
  .from('avatars')
  .upload('public/avatar1.png', avatarFile)
```

Unfortunately Supabase expects a `File` type.

In my API I have a url that points to the image I want to save, what's the best way for me to get the image at my URL as a File in Node.js?

I have tried this:

```
  let response;
  try {
    // fetch here is from the isomorphic-unfetch package so I can use it sever-side
    response = await fetch('https://example.com/image.jpeg');
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }

  let data = await response?.blob();

  let metadata = {
    type: 'image/jpeg',
  };

  let file = new File([data], 'test.jpg', metadata);
  return file;
```

But I get a `ReferenceError: File is not defined`, which leads me to believe only the browser has access to creating a `new File()`.

All I can find are answers about `fs`, which I think is Google getting confused. I don't think I can use `fs` to return a `File` type.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, this isn't actually possible. I've tried a lot of npm packages that advertise being able to convert blobs to `File`s, but none of them seemed to work.

The only actual solution is to download the file as the other answers have suggested, but in my situation it just wasn't doable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
const fspromise = require('fs').promises;
 let response;
  try {
    // fetch here is from the isomorphic-unfetch package so I can use it sever-side
    response = await fetch('https://example.com/image.jpeg');
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }

  let data = await response?.blob();

  let metadata = {
    type: 'image/jpeg',
  };

const file = blob2file(data);

function blob2file(blobData) {
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.set('a', blobData);
  return fd.get('a');
}


const { data, error } = await supabase.storage
  .from('avatars')
  .upload('public/avatar1.png', file)
```

Comment: That doesn't work for remote URLs unfortunately. I think it's just for local files.

Comment: Why don't you temp download the file and read it from the storage and send it to the supabase. I will try to think more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: That's not an option unfortunately, it would be too intensive for the API.

Comment: try this if it works, actually you need to use the Filesystem to get the file type.

Answer (score 1):

So what you can do is: send an HTTP request to the file

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http'); // maybe https?

const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('image.png');

const request = http.get('URL_HERE', function(response) {
  response.pipe(fileStream);
});
```

The above code fetches and writes the file from the URL to your server, and then you need to read it and send it to the upload process.

```
const finalFile = fs.readFileSync( 'image.png', optionsObject );
```

And now you have your file object do your upload, then don't forget to remove it if not needed anymore.

Comment: `createWriteStream` returns a `WriteStream`, not a `File`. This doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Thank you for the edit but I can't write the file to my server to then upload it, it would be too resource intensive.

Comment: absolutely right, I'll think about an alternative solution.